# add post type pram to wp shortcode

Tags: shortcode, post-type

hello i have this [program](https://jsfiddle.net/pj2pswxd/) (show posts with ajax paganition and ajax category filters) and its works fine what i want its add a pram that accept post type in shortcode because i need it to show posts from 2 diffrent post type movies and series. i've try a several way to do that but not work at all. hope you guys help me out.

my shortcode:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[ajax_filter_movies per_page="10"]'); ?>
```

which works fine but i want it be like :

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[ajax_filter_movies post_type="movies" per_page="10"]'); ?>
```

basic codes from [here](https://www.bobz.co/filter-wordpress-posts-by-custom-taxonomy-term-with-ajax-and-pagination/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to be able to switch between post types?

If not, seems to me you could just duplicate the same functionality as you're using with the per_page parameter, meaning:

In your shortcode function just add a data attr to the #container-async div for the post_type(s).

`<div id="container-async" data-paged="<?php echo $a['per_page']; ?>" data-posttype="<?php echo $a['post_type']; ?>" class="sc-ajax-filter">`

(you'll need to add it to your shortcode_atts as well by adding 'post_type' => '')

Then in your Javascript on('click') function add it to $params:

```
$params    = {
    'page' : $page,
    'tax'  : $this.data('filter'),
    'term' : $this.data('term'),
    'qty'  : $this.closest('#container-async').data('paged'),
    'pt'   : $this.closest('#container-async').data('posttype')
};
```

Finally, in your php function where you gather your $args array for WP_Query, get the value and then add in the post_type:

`$pt  = $_POST['params']['pt'];`

```
$args = array(
    'paged'          => $page,
    'post_type'      => $pt,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => $qty,
    'tax_query'      => $tax_qry
);
```

Comment: thanks for your time and answer sir i add your codes and call my shortcode like this : `<?php echo do_shortcode('[ajax_filter_movies post_type="movies" per_page="10"]'); ?>` but still its not work and show all posts from both post types.

Comment: okay i add this `sanitize_text_field()` and now its work but the problem is its only show 1 shortcode each time i mean when i use 2 short code just 1 of them shows and the other show nothing,have no idea why its dont show 2 shortcodes at same time

Comment: update your question to show me your whole shortcode function, the JS code, and the function hooked to the AJAX call. It's hard to envision what you mean when I can't see exactly what you're working with.

Comment: hey i [update my codes](https://jsfiddle.net/pj2pswxd/) every things works fine just dont know why 2 shortcodes dosent work at same time just 1 of them works and the other show's nothing at all.

Comment: does the second shortcode output anything at all? Not even the HTML? If that's the case, I assume your `if (count($terms))` returns false in the second shortcode and that's why nothing is output. Have you tried putting in a var_dump($terms) right before the if statement?

Comment: you can see live version of [my theme here](http://qsdl.test.pgraph.ir/) as you can see its just show taxonomy's and not show posts in second shortcode

Comment: remember that I'm not familiar with your theme or data. Where are the shortcodes? There is a lot of stuff on this page.

Comment: oh sorry sir i make some changes in theme for you [now you can see where is short codes](http://qsdl.test.pgraph.ir/).

Comment: one thing I noticed right away is that you have 2 divs with the ID "container-async" which is problematic, especially for the javascript.

Comment: so can i just use if to change divs ID's base on post types and tell java if post type = series use another div ?

Comment: I would start by changing it to `<div class="container-async"` and then in your JS appropriately `$('#container-async')` becomes `$('.container-async')`

Comment: now both shortcodes are works but both of them [show same post's from 1 post type.](http://qsdl.test.pgraph.ir/)

Comment: yeah, looking at your JS fiddle it seems that you hardcode the posttype in the WP_Query args. You'll need to pull it from the JS Ajax call. See my original answer.